# Write Access records into a SQL table using C# SqlConnection

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have a table in Access with Columns A, B, and C. I want to write the records in this table into a SQL table with Columns A, B, C and D. What's the best way to achieve it?

I tried using OleDbDataReader and bulkCopy, but the schema difference made it hard:

```
OleDbDataReader reader;// = new OleDbDataReader();

using (OleDbConnection sourceConnection = new OleDbConnection(sourceConnectionString))
        {
            //Get data from Access
            OleDbCommand commandSourceData = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM AddressLoCo;", sourceConnection);
            commandSourceData.Connection = sourceConnection;
            sourceConnection.Open();

            reader = commandSourceData.ExecuteReader();

            using (SqlConnection destinationConection = new SqlConnection(destinationConnectionString))
            {
                destinationConection.Open();
                // Set up the bulk copy object
                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConection))
                {
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.AddressMaster";

                    try
                    {
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
             }
          }
```

Comment: What schema difference? Could you be more specific?

Comment: You can link the SQL table in Access and you can also use a suitable connection string in-line in Access SQL to write to an SQL server table. By far the easiest is to link the SQL server table to Access. I can provide more information on the SQL if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [SqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.columnmappings.aspx) for all columns existing in your data source:

```
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("A", "A");
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("B", "B");
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("C", "C");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using Bulk Copy, which expects the schema of source and destination tables to be the same.

You would need to either process each record at a time or, better, create SSIS package.

Comment: Could you show me how to process one record at a time? I have about 200k records to process, not sure how the performance would be like. I'm not familiar with SSIS package, might have to give it a try tho.

Comment: @Venny There should not be any reason to process one record at a time.  Why not just use the Access connection to add all the records?

Comment: @Remou I'm not sure what you mean by using Access connection. Can you show me?

Comment: @Venny, I have added an outline answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Access connection, you can have something on these lines.

```
//The square brackets contain a valid connection to SQL Server, this is most 
//easily obtained by linking a table and checking the Connect property

string ssql = @"INSERT INTO [ODBC;Description=Test;DRIVER=SQL Server;
   SERVER=servername;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
   DATABASE=Test].table_1 (Atext)
   SELECT AText FROM Table1";
string sourceConnectionString = 
   @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=z:\docs\test.accdb;";
using (OleDbConnection sourceConnection = new OleDbConnection(sourceConnectionString))
{
    OleDbCommand commandSourceData = new OleDbCommand(ssql, sourceConnection);
    commandSourceData.Connection = sourceConnection;
    sourceConnection.Open();

    commandSourceData.ExecuteNonQuery();
```